# Parse txt file using a list of objects

Tags: vb.net, parsing, streamreader

I am trying to parse  a .txt file that has multiple loans in it. My logic is: I create a Loan class with the properties I need, I create a list of loan objects. I create a new loan object and add it to the list. I then read through the txt file and fill the objects properties. When I reach the end of the file I need to create a new loan object and start over because the file has multiple loans in it and I need one object per loan. The problem is when I use the code below I get the error "Local variable 'myLoans' hides a variable in an enclosing block". Is there a better way to do this?

```
    Public Class Loan
        Public Property LoanId As String
        Public Property LoanProvider As String
    End Class

    Dim listOfLoans As New List(Of Loan)()
    Dim myLoans As New Loan
    listOfLoans.Add(myLoans)

    Dim line As String
    Using r As New StreamReader("c:text.txt")
        line = r.ReadLine()
        Do While (Not line Is Nothing)
            If (line.Substring(0, 10) = "Loan id:") Then
                myLoans.LoanId = line.Substring(10, line.Length - 10).Trim()

            ElseIf (line.Substring(0, 14) = "Loan Provider:") Then
                myLoans.LoanProvider = line.Substring(14, line.Length - 19).Trim()

            ElseIf (line.Substring(0, 30) = "Last line of file:") Then
                Dim myLoans As New Loan
                listOfLoans.Add(myLoans)

            End If
            line = r.ReadLine
        Loop
    End Using
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't tag as C# if the code is VB.

Comment: I tagged C#, because a C# solution will work as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In these lines you are creating a new instance of the class Loan and you assign this new instance to a different variable called with the same name of the external variable.
Of course the lifetime of this variable is limited to the enclosing ElseIf/End IF block  and has nothing to do with the first one. Just the name and the compiler warns you of the pitfall

```
ElseIf (line.Substring(0, 30) = "Last line of file:") Then
    Dim myLoans As New Loan
    listOfLoans.Add(myLoans)
End If
```

You should simply change the line in

```
ElseIf (line.Substring(0, 30) = "Last line of file:") Then
    myLoans = New Loan    'no Dim so the myLoans is the external one'
    listOfLoans.Add(myLoans)
End If
```

this will create a new instance of the Loan class and assign the reference to the same variable declared at the start

Comment: You would think that would work but I am getting more errors now. Thanks

Comment: Errors related to this change or of a different kind?